# How do I correct this code to make it generic?

Tags: java

I am beginning to learn to code but I don't know how to generate the CRUD Read method that is generic.
For the moment to test I am assigning the object to be of type Person in which the ID of the class is the identification card. The problem is when comparing the attribute that is sent by the read method so that it returns only the element of the same ID.

```
public Optional<P> read(String id){
    return list.stream().filter(P -> P.equals(id)).findFirst();
}
```

What other option can be used instead of the .equals () method because when using this, it returns Optional.empty?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Plase show a [mcve] that we can compile and run ourselves.

Comment: Hello, attach the code in the answers

Comment: You n eed to compare those generic fields based on something. Because of that, those generics will also need bounds (likely around a parent class for `Persona`, one with something like `#getName`). Then you would filter around that method.

Comment: @SebastU Please [edit] your question instead. I will flag the code posted below because it isn't an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `Predicate<P>` as an argument:

```java
    public Optional<P> read(Predicate<P> predicate){
        return lista.stream().filter(predicate).findFirst();
    }
```

And use it like following:

```java
    controladorPersona.read(p -> "0202".equals(p.getCedula()));
```

Yet anothe option is to create an interface (eg `HasId`) with a method like `String getId()` and implement it in the `Persona` class. Then you can define generic in the `ControladorPersona` like `<P super HasId>`. In this case read method might look like:

```java
    public Optional<P> read(String id){
        return lista.stream().filter(p -> id.equals(p.getId())).findFirst();
    }
```

The idea is to let ControladorPersona know how to extract identifier from an element.